# Can IDEA do the same if/else suggestions as Resharper?

Tags: intellij-idea

IDEA's developers are also developers of Resharper. And I like the way Resharper suggests refactoring if/else.

Can IDEA do the same? this feature does not come by default.

**EDIT**

Here are some Resharper feature I am referring to:

```
Original code:

static public string ToNonNullString(this XmlAttribute attr)
{
    if (attr != null)
        return attr.Value;
    else
        return string.Empty;
}

Suggestion: remove redundant 'else' resulting in following:

static public string ToNonNullString(this XmlAttribute attr)
{
    if (attr != null)
        return attr.Value;
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Source is here (
[Code suggestions by Resharper making code less readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467389/code-suggestions-by-resharper-making-code-less-readable)).

I remember when I use Visual Studio with Resharper I get a lot of similar suggestions. Have not seen that in IDEA although I've been using it for 2 years.

Comment: What quick fix are you referring to? Please provide an example.

Comment: Did a big overhaul of my answer to show you how you can make IDEA report them, and not just fix them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Using this Java code:

```java
public class Test {
    public String notNull(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            return str;
        } else {
            return "empty";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following suggestions when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (`Show intentions`) on the `else`:
[image: Options]

Selecting `Remove Redundant 'else'` converts the method to this:

```java
public String notNull(String str) {
    if (str != null) {
        return str;
    }
    return "empty";
}
```

You can make IDEA report these automatically when you run an inspection. In Settings, go to Inspections, find `Confusing 'else' branch` in the Control flow-category. And check the `Also report when there are no more statements after the 'if' statement`.
[image: inspections]

Then running an inspection with that profile will show that you have a confusing else branch, and you can fix it with a click.

[image: remove]